# Maximum number of possible paths in an absorbing markov chain

Tags: combinatorics, markov-chains, markov-process

What is the maximum number of possible paths in an absorbing markov chain starting form a random transient state?

Comment: I suppose this depends on the chain. Are you asking on largest across all possible chains?

Comment: Am asking for number of possible chains in worst case ? starting from a transient state ending at the absorbing state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the worst case, consider your Markov chain as a triangle, with vertices $A,B,C$ and $A$ absorbing, with all other transitions of equal weight (i.e. moving from $B$ or from $C$, you end up at $A$ with probability $1/2$).

It is clear that even in this simple construction, there is a (countably) infinite number of possible paths, e.g. BA, BCA, BCBA, BCBCA, etc.

Note that each path of bigger length ends up exponentially less probable, which is what makes the final distribution collapse to $(p_A, p_B, p_C) = (1,0,0)$.

Of course, starting at $C$, the situation will be symmetric...

Comment: @Souvik Consider a complete graph on vertices $V = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ with vertex $0$ absorbing and $(1,0) \in E$, with no other transitions to $0$. Then, there will be $n^m$ paths of length $m+1$ that reach the absorbing state on the last move. It still is countable...